# What is the difference between operators and connectives?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, modal-logic

In the logic context, both the terms *operator* and *connective* is used. I wish to know what their differences are. Do we use an operator when we have something that effect only one formula and connective when it some sort of connect two formulae and effect both?

Comment: No difference in classical propositional logic; see [Logical connectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective). But see [Truth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_function) and [Modal operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_operator): *necessity* and *possibility* are not connectives.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but my immediate thought is that connectives are more syntactic, while operators are more semantic. That is, seen as a connective, something like the 'and' is just a way to take two sentences and connect them into a single sentence.  The 'not', which takes only a single sentence, is still a connective of sorts in that it takes in a senetence (e.g. the ball is red') and outputs another ('the ball is not red'). But as an operator, the 'and' and 'not' would be seen as a truth-functions: a function that takes in truth-values and outputs another truth-value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An operator is a more general category than connective.

In propositional logic, the only kinds of operators are connectives, which operate on truth values to produce a truth value for the combined formula.

But in predicate logic, we also have quantifiers ($\forall$ (= "for all"), $\exists$ (= "there exists")), which operate on individuals from a domain to compute a truth value. In modal logic, we have modal operators ($\Box$ (= "necessarily"), $\Diamond$ (= "possibly")), which take into account possible worlds. An so on.